# Is there a widely accepted way to structure a Flask route with many points of failure?

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a Flask application with a route that performs extensive processing of data before a response is returned to the user. Each step of this data processing has its own function, and each function is a potential point of failure. Each function returns some piece of data that is used to either build the response, or is used in the next function. In the event of a failure, the route should return a proper error message and status code based on where the failure occurred.

My first, naive approach was to individually wrap each function call in a try-except block, then return an error message and status code if an error was raised. This resulted in a wall of try-except blocks that worked, but looked poorly developed.

Is there a widely accepted structure or best practice for routes that have many potential points of failure?

Comment: If you want specific, detailed error messages for each failure case, then I think your naive approach will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help you: [sample structure](https://github.com/tanthienqn/sample-flask-structure).

In app, you can use `register_error_handler` to apply a handle exception before responding to user without use try-except.

See this [file](https://github.com/tanthienqn/sample-flask-structure/blob/main/server/middlewares/HandleError.py), It help you to format error response